# Trying accessing and setting image from a class that is not implementing it xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi everybody  i have a listview that contains all the contacts of my phone am trying in my xml file to set a image to all of them and trying to set invisible the ones that i don't need to appear i have this :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

    while (phones.moveToNext()){
        String name = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNumber = phones
                .getString(phones
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);         //
        list.add(objContact);

    }
    phones.close();


        for (int i = 0; i < SQLiteCrudEmc2.Emc2Contacts.length; i++) {

            if(!test(SQLiteCrudEmc2.Emc2Contacts[i].toString()) ){
                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                     Log.i("eeeeeeee",SQLiteCrudEmc2.Emc2Contacts[i].toString() );
                Toast.makeText(ContactListActivity.this, "Numéro retrouvé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// My problem here
            }
        }


    ContanctAdapter objAdapter = new ContanctAdapter(
            ContactListActivity.this, R.layout.alluser_row,list);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    if (null != list && list.size() != 0) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ContactBean>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ContactListActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("");


    } else {
        showToast("No Contact Found!!!");
    }
}
```

My contats adapter here :

```
public class ContanctAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactBean> {

private Activity activity;
private List<ContactBean> items;
private int row;
private ContactBean objBean;
ImageView img;

ViewHolder holder;
public ContanctAdapter(Activity act, int row, List<ContactBean> items) {
    super(act, row, items);

    this.activity = act;
    this.row = row;
    this.items = items;
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null)||((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);
    holder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
            && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
    }
    if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
            && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
    }

    return view;
}



public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvname, tvPhoneNo;
    ImageView img;

}
public class IsInMyContactsList extends Activity {
    public IsInMyContactsList(){

    }

    public  Boolean test(String num){

        Boolean isOk = false;
        Cursor phone1 = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,null, null);

        while (phone1.moveToNext()){

            String phoneNumber = phone1
                    .getString(phone1  
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if(num.equals(phoneNumber)) 

                isOk = true;

    }
        phone1.close();


        return isOk;

    }

}
```

}

i have a Java.lang.NullPointerExeption please help.

Comment: if(userHasPhoto()){ holder.image.setImage(...);}else{holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE)}

You could also use View.INVISIBLE to just make it disappear but still take space in the layout.

You have to do this in your adapter, where you bind data to the views (in the getView() method).

Comment: ok ~@DavidCorsalini let me try what u suggest tankx for help

Comment: here is my xml file i have set the same image for all my contacts

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"                     
        android:contentDescription="@string/descIm1" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
         />   
         
       </LinearLayout>
 
     </RelativeLayout> now i am trying in the code to access and set it invisible for those i wish

Comment: You have to declare the image in the XML used in the ContactAdapter. In this xml you will have an image for the profile pic, a textview for the name and a textview for the phone number.
In the getView() method in the adapter you already look for the image in the xml, so I guess you already have this layout.

Comment: there is no xml declared for the contact adapter i am using a Listview and an adapter so image is juste in the xml that my listview will call

Comment: A ListView take its views from an Adapter. You need to change 'row ' in this    view = inflater.inflate(row, null); with 'R.layout.your_row_layout' . 

your_row_layout is the xml that represents a single row in the xml.

Comment: ok @DavidCorsalini i try and let you know

Comment: it doesn't solve the probleme too but tkx for your answers